# Windows 10 settings tool bar has strange shading

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I have a laptop running Windows 10 64 bit (original).

When I open my settings the column or bar on the left has a kind of dark black shading at places.

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

It was very dark the first time I opened it and restarting the computer made it a lighter shade.

What is the problem? All other pages are fine, only the left bar is different.

Answer (score 0):

It's partially translucent. The difference is caused by blurred windows underneath.